# Embedding text file in latex document

Tags: verbatim, text

How do you remove the extra comments from a text file which has been embedded in a latex document?

```
\documentclass[12pt,bibtotoc,liststotoc,BCOR5mm,DIV12]{book}



\usepackage{listings, color}    
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}




    %redefine \VerbatimInput
\RecustomVerbatimCommand{\VerbatimInput}{VerbatimInput}%
{fontsize=\footnotesize,
 %
 frame=lines,  % top and bottom rule only
 framesep=2em, % separation between frame and text
 rulecolor=\color{Blue},
 %
 label=\fbox{\color{Blue}1985.txt},
 labelposition=topline,
 %
 commandchars=\|\(\), % escape character and argument delimiters for
                      % commands within the verbatim
 commentchar=*        % comment character
}
\begin{document}

\VerbatimInput{\input{text/1985.txt}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You have input `.tex` because `\verbatiminput` was expecting a filename but you supplied `\input{text/1985.txt}` so it took the tokens before `\input` that is, the empty filename. Do you _really_ have to load all those packages to make an example document? (also you are missing `\documentclass`)

Comment: @ David Carlisle : Please what point are you trying to make? I'm sorry I don't really get the explanation.So, what should I exactly do to remove the extra comment?.......All those packages are not needed but was wondering may be there shouldn't be a package there (working on a project document).... –

Comment: I assume you want `\VerbatimInput{text/1985.txt}` not `\VerbatimInput{\input{text/1985.txt}}` to avoid inputting the file `.tex` the rest of the comment was just to encourage you to produce an example that people could use to test answers (still not possible as posted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want

```
\VerbatimInput{text/1985.txt}
```

not

```
\VerbatimInput{\input{text/1985.txt}}
```

to avoid inputting the file `.tex`